# How to safely store a sting with apostrophe in JSONB in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a case where addresses and country names have special characters. For eg:

People's Republic of Korea
De'Paul & Choice Street
etc..

This data get send as JSON payload to backend to be inserted in a JSONB column in postgres.

The insert statement gets messed up because of the "single quote" and ends up erroring out.

The front-end developers are saying that they are using popular libraries to get country names etc and don't want to touch the data. They just want to pass as is.

Any tips on how to process such data with special characters especially something that contradicts with JSON formatted data and safely insert into postgres?

Comment: JSON(B) has no problems with apostrophes. If your "*insert statement gets messed up*" that must be because you're not properly escaping the SQL value literal in the query - and have an [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) security issue. Can you please show us the backend code that does the database call? Why are you not using a parameterised statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your developers are using the popular libraries, whatever they may be, in the wrong fashion. The application is obviously vulnerable to SQL injection, the most popular way to attack a database application.

Use prepared statements, then the problem will go away. If you cannot do that, use the popular library's functions to escape the input string for use as an SQL string literal.

Comment: "*Your developers are using the popular libraries in the wrong fashion*" - I think that statement about popular libraries refers to the frontend libraries that are providing the data with apostrophes, which is totally legitimate.

Comment: @Bergi That may well be; the question is rather vague. But I guess you agree that prepared statements are the solution.

Comment: Here is a sample record. The key issue is the "Apostrophe". If I used another country name like "France" this works....                    insert into companies ( company_details) 
values ('
{
    "companyName": "Apostrophe",
       "country": "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of",
    "companyUrl": ""
}
');